# Rails collection_check_boxes - wrap each checkbox with <li>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Brand new to Rails. How do I add a `<li>` wrapper to each checkbox / label element generated by the following code?

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :publish_to, [['YouTube'], ['Hulu'], ['Roku'], ['Owned Website'], ['Other']], :first, :first %>
```

The final outputted HTML would look like:

```
<li class="checkbox-wrap">
  <label></label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
</li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

It's possible. `collection_check_boxes` allows you to do it like this:

```
<ul>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :publish_to, [['YouTube'], ['Hulu'], ['Roku'], ['Owned Website'], ['Other']], :first, :first do |b| %>
  <li>
    <%= b.label %>
    <%= b.check_box %>
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Works on Rails 5 as well.

Reference: https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As per [collection_check_boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) the following should do (though, I never tried it myself):

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :publish_to, [['YouTube'], ['Hulu'], ['Roku'], ['Owned Website'], ['Other']], :first, :first do |b| %>
   <%= content_tag :li, "#{b.label { b.check_box } }", class: "checkbox-wrap" %>
<% end %>
```

Or something very similar.